# C# How to get fields of undefined variable when properties are set at runtime?

Tags: c#

Lets say this is my code:

```
private async void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.SelectedItem;
    
    if (item == null)
        return;
    
    ...
}
```

I have an undefined variable since I dont know the type of e.SelectedItems.
If I set a stoppoint at the `if`, I can see the field of `item`. One of them is `Title`.

How can I access `title` when I dont know the type of the variable (`var item`)?

Comment: Cast `e.SelectedItem` to whatever type you put in the list in the first place.

Comment: Do you know what type it is going to be or is it varying? If you do know what it is, you can just cast it to the concrete type.

Comment: Yep, just found it out. Thank you. If you post as answer i will accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found the type and casted:

```
string title = ((Types)item).Title;
```